# Postgres Glassfish Pooling

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, connection-pooling

Some tutorial says use `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource` but some says just the `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`... what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the class `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource` implements **Connection Pooling**, therefore it can provide some performance benefits.

According to the documentation:

[Class PGSimpleDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html)

> Simple DataSource which does not perform connection pooling. In order
>   to use the DataSource, you must set the property databaseName. The
>   settings for serverName, portNumber, user, and password are optional.
>   Note: these properties are declared in the superclass.

[Class PGConnectionPoolDataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.html)

> PostgreSQL implementation of ConnectionPoolDataSource. The app server
>   or middleware vendor should provide a DataSource implementation that
>   takes advantage of this ConnectionPoolDataSource. If not, you can use
>   the PostgreSQL implementation known as PoolingDataSource, but that
>   should only be used if your server or middleware vendor does not
>   provide their own. Why? The server may want to reuse the same
>   Connection across all EJBs requesting a Connection within the same
>   Transaction, or provide other similar advanced features.

See also:

- [Connection Pooling with PostgreSQL JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203989/connection-pooling-with-postgresql-jdbc)